# Monitor HTML and add changes to an input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an indeterminate number of span and input tags with random IDs.
The user has the ability to change the HTML inside of `<span>` but not `<input>`.

It looks like this:

```
<span id="0">235</span>
<input id="5239aac3" value=235>

<span id="1">12</span>
<input id="123abc2" value=12>

<span id="2">235</span>
<input id="5res345" value=235>
```

I have put all the IDs of `<input>` into an array called `arrayOfIDs` and through JavaScript given all matching `<span>` tags and Id of the index.

```
for (var i = 0, l = arrayOfIDs.length; i < l; ++i) {

 $('#' + i).on("change", function(){
   var txt = $(this).find().text();
   var $idval = $(arrayOfIDs[i]);
   $idval.val(txt)
 }).trigger("change");    
}
```

What I need help with in the code above is how to monitor the change in the innerHTML of all spans and update the corresponding input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to change your first selector from `$('#i')` to `$('#' + i)`

otherwise you're selecting the element with the literal id of 'i' , which doesn't exist

Also, is the function firing at all?  If so, what output do you get?

Finally, I think that you'll want to change `var $idval = $(arrayOfIDs[i]);` to `var $idval = $('#' + arrayOfIDs[i]);`

Comment: would like to, but I am of insufficient reputation. :(